# Is there a Lotus view formula to find mails which were sent outside of the local domain?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus-formula

Somehow my corporate email address has found its way onto a spam/phish list. I suppose it's unavoidable, but I can't think of any time that I've sent an email to an external address and I'm very curious to know how it could have 'escaped'.

I would like to create a SELECT formula to find any mails where one or more recipients are external (ie. do not end with '@mycompany.com', '@mycompany.com>' or '/MYCOMPANY/COM'.

I've used '@Contains' in other queries, but @Contains and @Ends don't really do the job here. If they returned a count of the number of matches, then I could compare it to the total number of recipients. Any mails where these totals are unequal will be the ones I'm looking for. But they only return booleans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this (do NOT mix MYDOMINODOMAIN with /MYCOMPANY/COM):

```
_myDomains := @Lowercase("MYDOMINODOMAIN" : "mycompany.com" : "mycompany.net");
_mailRecipientString := @LowerCase(@ReplaceSubstring(SendTo : CopyTo : BlindCopyTo : Recipients; @Char(13) : @Char(9) : @Char(34) : @Char(39) : "," : "<" : ">" : "\"" : " " ; " "));
_mailRecipientValues := @Explode(@Implode(_mailRecipientString;" "); " "; @False);
_mailDomains := @Unique(@Trim(@Explode(@Implode(@Word(_mailRecipientValues; "@"; 2); " "); " "; @False)));

SELECT @Trim( @Replace( _mailDomains ; _myDomains ; "" ) ) != ""
```

What does this formula do?

Every address in SendTo, CopyTo, BlindcopyTo and (this is for paranoia as it contains the three former) Recipients ALWAYS has an @. I get the domains of this addresses using @Word.

Then I replace the "good" domains in this list with an empty string (@Lowercase to be sure). If the result is something different than the empty string -> Found one

Comment: That works great, thankyou! Although I noticed that email addresses seem to come in so many different formats (with/without names, quote marks, angle brackets, and even tab characters). So I've tweaked the code a little bit. It works with everything we have now... maybe could be more efficient though. I'm still new to @Formulas. Thanks again!!